# Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter returns NULL

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

i'm trying to use

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

But it returns NULL

I tried to add

```
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter                  = true
```

in my application.ini but no changes at all...

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you check the first two q&a in the **Related** column? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159833/in-zend-framework-zend-db-tablegetdefaultadapter-returns-null?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491681/zend-db-adapter-suddenly-is-null?rq=1. Also, from Search results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029307/no-default-adapters-in-zend-unless-i-add-them-explicitly-is-this-a-feature-or-a If these don't help, can you please point out why they didn't help?

Comment: Are you going through a proper bootstrap phase?

Comment: Are you trying to execute `$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();` in bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following function into Bootstrap

```
protected function _initDatabase() {

    $db = $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db); //important
    Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

in the end of file PROJECTNAME\public\.htaccess